# How do I select an item from a list created in Scratch?

Tags: drop-down-menu, mit-scratch

My son and I are learning how to program in Scratch from MIT. I have learned using the variables tools how to create a list but I cannot work out how to select an item from the list I created and to use that selection for the next command. How do I do it?

By the way, is there a way to export Scratch graphic script as a text script for sharing here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For getting a text version of scripts, you can use "write project summary" from the menu.

Comment: @blob8108 Note that you have to Shift-click the File menu for that to be available. It produces Scratchblocks output, so it'd be most useful for posting on the Scratch forums that will visualize it and then linking to the forum post.

Comment: @Noumenon "write project summary" does not produce valid scratchblocks code.

Comment: If you surround it with [scratchblocks][/scratchblocks], anything that's not a real block, like the sound file names, will display as a red block, and everything else will display just as it is in the project. For debugging help that should be just fine. Example I just made with no editing: http://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/14778/?page=86#post-537404

Answer (score 5):

There should be a block under 'Variables' called `item [] of []` - see http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Item_%28%29_of_%28%29_%28block%29.  Set the first blank to the index you want to select, and the second to the name of the list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a block under 'Variables' called `item [] of []`. did you make a list creation script? in that case, put the list name in the dropdown menu as you put it in the `add [] to []` block. hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

This may help:
[Item [ ] of List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY9rt.png)

This block is under the tab 'Variables'.  To get to it, first, you must create a list.